# Creating Log-normal distribution curves with Jstat using json data

Tags: json, plot, distribution, jstat

There is no documentation for jStat. As of 2012-11-06 ([per the documentation page](http://www.jstat.org/documentation)): "The jStat API documentation is still being compiled."

I want  to plot log-normal curves with JSON data. Can anyone who have worked on this throw some light on how to get started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project repo is at https://github.com/jstat/jstat

Current documentation for jStat is at http://jstat.github.com/

The webpage is using a version of jStat that is no longer worked on. The current project has focused on extending functionality so it is more easily integrated into your graphing library of choice. There is a simple UI repo (but hasn't been worked on much) at https://github.com/jstat/jstat-ui